# Lazy evaluation of Dask arrays to avoid temporaries

Tags: dask

Coming from C++, I am used to libraries using expression templates where matrix operations like:

```
D = A*(B+C)
```

do not create temporaries and the element-wise

```
D(i,j) = A(i,j)*(B(i,j)+C(i,j))
```

operation is done inside the loop without creating temporary matrices for the operations in the right hand side.

Is this possible with Dask arrays? Does the Dask "lazy evaluation" also do this or this term just refers to the computation on demand of the operation graph.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018-11-11 the answer is "yes, dask array avoids full temporaries at the large scale but, no, it doesn't avoid allocating temporaries at the Numpy/blockwise level".

Dask arrays are composed of many Numpy arrays.  And Dask array operations are achieved by performing those operations on the Numpy array chunks.  When you do `A * (B + C)` that operation happens on every matching set of numpy array chunks as numpy would perform the operation, which includes allocating temporaries.

However, because Dask can operate chunk-wise it doesn't have to allocate all of the `(B + C)` chunks before moving on.

You're correct that because Dask is lazy is has an opportunity to be more clever than Numpy here.  You can track progress on this issue here: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4038